# create 2 lines plot by dates of Trump's tweets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have series of Trump's tweets sources by date:

```
trump_tweets_sources.groupby(['  created_at  ', '  source  '])['  source  '].count()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y12Cf.png)

I want to create 2 lines plot describes the sources tweets by date, one for iPhone and one for Android

How can I do that?

Comment: How is created your data? Can you add your code to question?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for `DataFrame` and then use [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
s = trump_tweets_sources.groupby(['  created_at  ', '  source  '])['  source  '].count()

s.unstack().plot()
```